# How can i search for listView specific item/s using textBox textchanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items)
            {
                if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    item.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                    item.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Selected = false;
                    item.BackColor = Color.White;
                    item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Focus();
            }
        }
```

For example in the listView if i have 30 items and i type in the textBox F so it will show me all the items with F but then i keep typing Form1 then it should automatic narrow the results only to this with Form1 i mean color them in CornflowerBlue or better in Red.

So first when i type only F it will color in red many items then i keep typing Form1 so it will color less items and so on.

This code is not coloring at all.

Comment: I just tried with your code. It works perfectly. Do you having any error?

Comment: @codelahiru no matter what i type in the textBox form1 or Form1 or FORM1 it's getting all the time to the Black and White colors and never to the CornflowerBlue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextChanged` event is on `textBox4`, but your code is checking the text of `textBox1`.

I would imagine you would want to be checking the text on the same TextBox that you are typing the filter in.

Change

```
if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
```

To

```
if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox4.Text.ToLower()))
```

Comment: Ooops ... My mistake sorry.

Comment: No problem. It's just one of those lessons everyone learns where they now start to name variable and controls properly instead of `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, etc. Also a single breakpoint and some debugging would have shown the issue  ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just add `item.Remove()`  inside the else part. Then it will narrow down the list. **But you need to keep those removed items else where and add appropriately.** otherwise it will be a empty list.

```
item.Selected = false;
item.BackColor = Color.White;
item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
item.Remove();
```

[image]

Comment: No i don't want to narrow the list of items in the listView but to narrow the number of items to be colored. If i type only F it will color almost all the items since the letter F might be exist in many of the items text. But if i will keep typing Form1 then it will narrow the number of items to be colored. Not narrow the number of items. The idea is just to search in the items not to remove them .

Answer (score 0):

i build the form and use your code (without "ListViewCostumControl.lvnf")
and it's worked well.
this is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        //Add column header
        listView1.Columns.Add("ProductName", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Price", 70);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 70);

        //Add items in the listview
        string[] arr = new string[4];
        ListViewItem itm;

        //Add first item
        arr[0] = "product_1";
        arr[1] = "100";
        arr[2] = "10";
        itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
        listView1.Items.Add(itm);

        //Add second item
        arr[0] = "product_2";
        arr[1] = "200";
        arr[2] = "20";
        itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
        listView1.Items.Add(itm);
    }


    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                item.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                item.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Selected = false;
                item.BackColor = Color.White;
                item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            listView1.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

so maybe the probkem in "ListViewCostumControl.lvnf"..

Comment: Not sure where is the problem. In my case no matter what i type in the textBox if it's only one letter 'F' or if it's Form1 or FORM1 or form1 or just form in all the cases it's getting to the White and Black colors part. And never get to the CornflowerBlue color part.